# Move files from repo-a to repo-b(existing repo) subdirectory including git history

Tags: git, github, merge

I have a requirement to move the files from one repository to another repository subdirectory including the git history.
I have followed this below link, but it's actually merging the two repos into the repo-b root folder.

https://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/git-combine/

But I want to merge the repo-a content into repo-b sub dir like repo-b/newdir/.

I also tried with the git subtree command, which helped me to add the repo-a into repo-b/newdir/.

> git subtree add --prefix=newdir repo-a_URL BRANCH_NAME

But when I am trying to push it to the remote repo, it complains that my UserID and email are not matching with the old commit ids and emails.

**example error log when i use subtree command:**

remote: - Bitbucket: 'sarva' != Commit: 'test, user'
remote:   **************************** Message ******************************
remote: Committer name in your git user.name is not matching with bitbucket user slug. Please make sure you have mentioned correct network id under your git user.name.
remote:

So can anyone please help me with it please.?